# Where to define webservices as asynchronous?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios, data-access

I'm working on a iOS project and I'm asking myself a question for a couple of days.
My problem is simple: I have webservice calls which are synchronous. But I would like to do asynchronous calls. But I don't know where to define the fact calls should be asynchronous.

Here is how my code works:
 - I have a controller (most of the
   time, a UITableViewController) The
   controller calls a DataAccess with
   some arguments to get data
 - DataAccess    calls a webservice
   using given    arguments, transform
   result into an    NSArray containing
   Model object, and    return result to
   the controller

Should it be the controller or the DataAccess which defines that my call will be asynchronous?

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your communicating with your web service.  My company developed a REST implementation for this purpose (easier than SOAP for iOS purposes), and use asihttprequest to do the async calls.  Asihttprequest is used by many apps and very good imo.  Also, for data centric apps, we chose to put the calls in the model layer rather than the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's a third-party library that wraps and VASTLY simplifies HTTP client work.

It sounds to me like you're not hip to the delegate pattern yet. It's a critical part of working with Cocoa, so learn it up.